# Clustering points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, clustering, spatial-cluster

I am trying to cluster points in PostGIS. I have the points and the corresponding Latitudes and Longitudes which I have converted into point geometries. I want to cluster points in such a way that all the points within a cluster are within 25 miles of each other.

My input looks like this:

[image]

My desired output is this:

[image]

Here the new column `Cluster_id` denotes the cluster to which the point is assigned to. Please tell me the right query to get this done. I am new to SQL so I am finding hard to write the right query.

So far, I have tried this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(the_geom, 1))) FROM all_locations
```

Comment: Well, from the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterWithin.html), the 2nd parameter is the distance, which is stated in the units of your spatial reference system. I am guessing, in your case, this is lat/long (4326), so you are going to need to convert that 2nd parameter into 25 miles.  Ideally, use a projected coordinate system, as calculating distance in 4326 is a bit fiddly. You should update your question stating what is wrong with what you have so far tried.

Comment: This is best achieved using `ST_ClusterDBSCAN`; this is a window function and does not aggregate rows! Morning @JohnPowell, long time no chat in comments ;-)

Comment: Yes, but that creates clusters where points could be much more than 25 miles apart, as it is based on the distance between neighbouring points, not a global distance. A windowed version of ClusterWithin would be helpful.

Comment: Same same; `ST_ClusterWithin` will collect all geometries that are not separated more than the threshold *from each other*! `ST_ClsuterDBSCAN` will produce different results if `minpoints > 1`, but for `minpoints = 1` it produces the same result. For global distance (where the *cluster* radius is no more than a threshold) one would need a *kernel/moving window* based approach. However, the same issues concerning CRS units apply!

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest to use the `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` *Window function* rather than the *Aggregate function* `ST_ClusterWithin`:

```
SELECT *,
       ST_ClusterDBSCAN(the_geom, eps := <distance>, minpoints := 1) OVER() AS clst_id
FROM   all_locations
;
```

`clst_id` will hold `INT` values representing the cluster each rows geometry belongs to.

---

As stated in the comments, `ST_ClusterWithin` will aggregate geometries that are separated by no more than the `distance` *to each other*; using `minpoints := 1` in `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` will force the same effect.

Compare

```
WITH
    pts AS (
        SELECT  ST_MakePoint(n, 0) As geom
        FROM    Generate_Series(0, 5) AS n
    )

SELECT  dmp.clst_id
FROM    (
    SELECT  ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 1) AS cw
    FROM    pts
) AS    clst,
        UNNEST(clst.cw) WITH ORDINALITY AS dmp (clst, clst_id),
        LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_CollectionExtract(dmp.clst, 1)) AS extr
;


 clst_id |    geom    
---------+------------
       1 | POINT(0 0)
       1 | POINT(1 0)
       1 | POINT(2 0)
       1 | POINT(3 0)
       1 | POINT(4 0)
       1 | POINT(5 0)
(6 rows)
```

to

```
WITH
    pts AS (
        SELECT  ST_MakePoint(n, 0) As geom
        FROM    Generate_Series(0, 5) AS n
    )

SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 1, 1) OVER() AS clst_id,
       ST_AsText(geom) AS geom
FROM   pts
;


 clst_id |    geom    
--------+------------
      0 | POINT(0 0)
      0 | POINT(1 0)
      0 | POINT(2 0)
      0 | POINT(3 0)
      0 | POINT(4 0)
      0 | POINT(5 0)
(6 rows)
```

In both cases the geometries are stretched over a total distance of 5 degrees, but count as one and the same cluster (`ST_ClusterDBSCAN` starts counting at 0, whereas the `ORDINALITY` stars at 1) since they are within `distance/eps` of 1 degree *to each other*!

This behavior may change for `minpoints > 1` (and on other data than the above), as there need to be at least `minpoints` *core* geometries within `eps` distance to get counted as cluster.

Needless to say, the latter approach is *way* less convoluted, and offers some nice functionality built into the windowing behavior (e.g. easy clustering over attributes etc.)

---

**Note:**

Both functions assume `distance/eps` **in units of the underlying CRS**; for a geographic reference system, this is *degrees*! Since there is no signature accepting `GEOGRAPHY` for neither of them, you will need to `ST_Transform` your data into a suitable projection to be able to work with metric/imperial units.

Comment: Good answer as always. I have started playing with cuSpatial and other RapidsAI algorithms, as I was starting to feel the pain with certain types of Postgis query (kNN, being a particular pain point). Obviously, not deserting Postgres/Postgis, but there are some algos for which GPU speedups are impossible to ignore.

Comment: Thank You for your detailed and prompt answer @ThingumaBob. I have implemented your solution but what I have noticed is that in DBSCAN, all the points within a cluster are reachable from another point that is 25 miles away from it. But, I wanted to build clusters in such a way that every point within a cluster is less than 25 miles away from every other points within that cluster.

Comment: @KarthikKatragadda indeed, they do in both functions...in fact, no function does what you ask for, and for a reason; consider the example above (line of points, separated by 1 deg), where would you want the clusters to start and end? Is P(0 0)+P(1 0) a cluster, and eventually P(5 0) left out? Even in this very simple case, clustering with a global cluster radius s ambiguous, in real world data sets this ends up being totally random, if doable at all (computationally). A *moving window* approach might at least get you consistent assignments, but there is no out-of-the-box solution in PostGIS